# An RSA cipher has the public key pq=65 and e=7. What is the encrypted value of 3 integers a,b and c.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

Question: An RSA cipher has the public key pq=65 and e=7. What is the encrypted value of 3 integers a,b and c.
$$ \begin{align*}
&M={ C }^{ d }mod\quad pq,\quad M\quad <\quad pq,\quad and\quad \\
&C={ M }^{ e }\\ 
&by\quad substitution,\\ 
&{ C }^{ d }mod\quad pq\quad =\quad ({ M }^{ e }\quad mod\quad pq{ ) }^{ d }mod\quad pq
\end{align*} $$

I have tried to research this question and found an overwhelming amount of information am not I am sure what my first steps should be, what the middle part is and how to end.

Comment: any 3 integers x, where 0≤x≤9

Comment: I want to say yes, we do not need the sum  of the digits encrypted. Just the separate integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \begin{align*}
&Assume\quad we\quad are\quad encrypting\quad 1\quad 2\quad 3\\
&C\quad =\quad Cyphertex,\quad M\quad =\quad Message\quad (plain\quad text)\\ 
&e\quad and\quad pq\quad =\quad public\quad key.\\ \\
&C\quad =\quad { M }^{ e }\quad mod\quad pq.\\ \\
&Let\quad pq\quad =\quad 65\\ 
&Let\quad e\quad =\quad 7\\ \\ 
&f(x)\quad =\quad { x }^{ 7 }\quad mod\quad 65\quad \\ \\ 
&f(1)\quad =\quad 1\\ 
&f(2)\quad =\quad 63\\ 
&f(3)\quad =\quad 42\\ \\ 
&123\quad \Rightarrow \quad RSA\quad 1\quad 63\quad 42
\end{align*} $$